# Postman Graphql Schema Refresh not working

Tags: graphql, postman

I am using postman for my qrpahql requests with spring boot.

When i try to refresh the schema my application gave an error.

```
graphql.AssertException: query can't be null
at graphql.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:17)
at graphql.ExecutionInput$Builder.query(ExecutionInput.java:204)
at 
graphql.kickstart.execution.input.GraphQLSingleInvocationInput.createExecutionInput(GraphQLSingleInvocationInput.java:47)
```

This is because postman sends the refresh query empty. Could you fix it @Postman Team

The query should be like this;

```
query IntrospectionQuery {
  __schema {
    queryType {
      name
    }
    mutationType {
      name
    }
    subscriptionType {
      name bla bla bla
```

Comment: This looks like a bug report. Have you tried [submitting a bug report](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues)